# Error On Updating MySQL table using CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a CodeIgniter Application that updates two columns in a table, using the "update()" helper method in codeigniter.

This is the controller:

```
      $data_v   = array(                
            "status" => $resp->Code
        );
        if($resp->Code == "0") {
            $data_v['name'] = $responseObject->AccountName;
                }
         $this->employees_model->update_employee($id, $data_v);
```

The model is :

```
     public function update_employee($id, $data) {

    $id = (int)$id;
    $this->db->where('empID', $id);
    $this->db->update('emp', $data);
}
```

The issue is that i get the following error:

```
 You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
  check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version   
   for    the    right syntax   to use near 'NEO WHERE `empID` = 20160'   at line 1


   UPDATE `emp` SET `status` = 0, 
  `name` = ALIBABA, THIEF NEO WHERE `empID` = 20160
```

My knowledge of SQL points to the fact (i believe) that the character value

```
     ALIBABA, THIEF NEO
```

needs to be enclosed in single quotes to look like this

```
    'ALIBABA, THIEF NEO'
```

How can i resolve this? and if the issue is not enclosing character values in quotes...what do i do?
Thanks

Comment: Does anyone following solution helps you?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are right you need to add `'` before and after string.

Change from

```
$data_v['name'] = $responseObject->AccountName;
```

into

```
$data_v['name'] = "'".$responseObject->AccountName."'";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use escape() method in db class to do it.
Escape method will find out datatype and add quotes to string.

Ex : $data_v['name'] = $this->db->escape($responseObject->AccountName);

Note : You can also use $this->db->escape_str();